# Почему функция возвращает промис?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция:

```
async function getLat() {
        let lat = await geocoder.geocode(cityName, (err, data) => {
            lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            return lat;
        }, { key: GOOGLE_API });
    }

console.log(getLat());
```

Почему результат её работы `Promise {<pending>}`?

Comment: потому что стоит `async`

Comment: Т.е я никак не смогу получить нужный мне результат таким способом?

Comment: нужный результат это какой? ты можешь написать `console.log(await getLat());`

Comment: Можно предположить ещё, что `await geocoder.geocode` — это ошибка, так как `geocoder.geocode` использует колбек, чтобы работать с результатом, а не возвращает промис. Если `data` доступно только внутри колбека, эти данные нельзя будет вернуть из `geocoder.geocode` без дополнительных ухищрений.

Comment: Я ожидаю, что ф-я вернёт координаты в формате 7.12389819. Попробовал `console.log(await getLat());` - получил `undefined`. 

Можно поподробнее о дополнительных ухищрениях?

Comment: Чтобы понять, что происходит, нужно знать, как работает `geocoder.geocode`. Это ваша функция или библиотечная? К ней есть документация?

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно вот это, если хотите работать в стиле промисов с функциями, использующими колбеки: https://learn.javascript.ru/promisify

Comment: С помощью `npm` установил пакет `"geocoder": "0.2.3"`. Вообще, ф-я работает нормально если я не пытаюсь получать значения асинхронно. У меня есть глобальная ф-я которая срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку, после этого я хотел с помощью ф-и 'getLat()` получать значение `lat` и это значение использовать в других функциях но так как переменная объявлена локально то в других функциях я не мог использовать её и пришел к решению в котором сам создам функцию и уже результат её работы буду использовать в других функциях:
Так же мой вопрос о этой теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1269373/389030

Comment: Думаю, чтобы не тыкать наугад в темноте, вам стоит разобраться с базовыми вещами в асинхронности. Проштудируйте https://learn.javascript.ru/async, если ещё не.